# Sci-fi pre-1985 children's(ish?) book series about a boy who lived next door to an old scientist

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

When I say this series has been haunting me for a couple of decades, it's an understatement. I remember *loving* this series, but I also remember it being a bit weird, and maybe even a bit science heavy for kids.

There were a number of books in it (I believe), and all I can remember is this young kid would go over to his neighbor's house, and the neighbor was an eccentric, old, scientist. I -feel- like they'd go to alternate dimensions and that sort of thing.

But the books themselves seemed old in 1986, so they might've been from the 70s?

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on here, can you not remember anything else that happens in it that you could edit in? [This guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) might be helpful to look at.

Comment: With so little information, the only thing coming to mind would be the Mushroom Planet books, which are decidedly science-light.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the living arrangement, this seems very much like the *Danny Dunn* books by Jay Williams and Raymond Abrashkin.  They were published from the mid-1950s until the late 1960s.

Danny's mother was the (live-in, with separate quarters) housekeeper for Professor Bullfinch, and Danny (along with his friend Joe and sometimes another friend, a girl whose name I've forgotten) would always get involved with the Professor's inventions.  The Professor had a frenemy (a term which hadn't been invented yet when the books were written), Professor Grimes.  The two would sometimes make music together; Bullfinch (a large, portly man) played a piccolo, while Grimes, a skeletal fellow, played a "bull fiddle" (a bowed upright bass).

There were about a dozen books in the series, with Danny and friends dealing with a supercomputer, a cryogenic thermocouple device, a high powered laser, a submarine -- and other stuff I've forgotten.

Comment: Yeah, what you said...

Comment: These were my favorite books when I was about ten... And apparently, they were still coming out.

Comment: Only a couple of the titles seem familiar.  My local library only had a couple of them, but a good number of Tom Swifts.

Comment: That series was the first thing that popped into my head, too. Can't remember the last time I actually read one of those books . . .

Comment: Was it Danny Dunn who stayed home sick from school one day and decided to make things easy for himself in bed and started setting up all kinds of string/pulley things in his room so he could fetch books, turn the lights on and off, etc. etc. etc.?  I'm pretty sure it was Danny Dunn.

Comment: Was it Danny Dunn who got stranded on a desert island with his friends and the Professor and so on and they were stuck with no resources until he turned out his pockets which were jammed with all kinds of useful stuff that enabled them to fish, repair a radio, etc. etc. etc. etc.?

Comment: @davidbak I don't recall that story, but apparently the second book, published 1957, was titled *Danny Dunn on a Desert Island* so this might well have been the case.